# Play DVD from US (non commercial) on UK DVD player or computer

Tags: television

I recently brought back some DVD's recorded at a conference in Florida, USA. They play on my UK DVD and computer but with with horizontal lines across the picture. Is this a region problem or a NTSC to Pal issue.

Comment: Classic interlacing issue. Try using VLC it has a deinterlacing feature. Or https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif-1

Answer (score 2):

If it was region locked, you would not be able to play the DVD at all (or gotten a warning that your DVD drive's region can only be changed 5 times). Therefore it is likely a video issue. If you're still using an old 4:3 TV or monitor it could be widescreen letterboxing but more likely it is the NTSC/PAL issue.

Comment: That it has the same problem when played on a computer seems strange though.

Comment: @RayButterworth Possibly there's some setting in his DVD player software.

Comment: DVD drives on computers unfortunately generally have the same region-locking as on non-computer DVD players.  There's a way you can change the region in the DVD drive settings, but most drives only allow you to do this a handful of times.  You might find more options if you asked this question on superuser.com.